# How to replace a value in a multidimensional javascript object using dynamic key generated from another object

Tags: javascript, object

I have 2 javascript objects one contains current values and the other contains they key of the value which needs to be replaced.

```
var values = {'instance': {'body' : {'background': '000000'}}};

var replace = {'scope':'instance', 'item':'body', 'property': 'background'};

var newValue = 'FFFFFF';

Values[replace.scope][replace.item][replace.property] = newValue;
```

I could 'hard code' replacement as shown above but is there a way to create the replacement dynamically using a map/loop of the 'replace' object as the multidimensional objects may vary in depth?

Comment: The problem with doing a loop on the replace object is that objects, and json objects, are not guaranteed to be in a particular order like arrays. So you can't reliably iterate over replace and determine the mapping structure of the values object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example being about modifying style is an example (otherwise I would advise you to use jQuery to modify styles):

You could do:

```
values.instance.body.background = newValue;
```

So if the replace instance is defined as it is and it can even go deeper, you could, in this case, do something like:

```
 var path = "";
 for(i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
    path += "." + replace[i];
 }
 eval(path + " = " + "'" + newValue + "'"); 
 //resulting in "values.instance.body.background = newValue" being executed;
```

Cheers!